# Sockets compatible with javascript on a remote shared server?

Tags: php, javascript, sockets, websocket

Basically I want to use some kind of sockets (web sockets or node.js?) but I don't really know much about them and I want to send low latency data between html pages with javascript enabled on them.

I have php installed on the shared server and socket_connect() is a function included so i'm guessing php_sockets.dll is installed. I could potentially use this, but the php script is on a remote server so I don't know if i would be able to run it?

Should I use some other language that would be installed on a normal shared server?

EDIT: I don't have shell access..

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more about what you are trying to do. Web sockets provide a socket like connection between the browser and server and allows more two way communication. Rather than the sumilated from in which a browser constantly polls a script via ajax. But its browser support is not complete yet.

Comment: i will have browser support. it's for a mobile app with 'phonegap' which allows me to write with html5 and js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.flynsarmy.com/2012/02/php-websocket-chat-application-2-0/ this should give you a pretty good start in talking to php using html5's websocket api. You don't need Node.js to implement this.

Comment: I don't have shell access. How might I bypass that step?

Comment: As I said above, it's a shared server so I have very little control over it.